# CNN-LSTM input shape incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to combine CNN and LSTM layers in a binary classifier, but the input shapes of the layers do not correspond to each other. What should I do?

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 512)
```

```
X_train.shape, X_test.shape
((19634, 1000, 12), (2203, 1000, 12))

y1.shape, y2.shape
((19634, 2), (2203, 2))
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: SO is in English only. Also no images of code or error. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Flatten layer turn 2-dim into 1-dim but as you know LSTM layer structure will only accept 2-dim in this shape (batch_size, sequence_length, dim) but Flatten layer output in shape (batch_size, dim), so you could comment Flatten layer in your model structure, or even You could use Lambda layer with expand dims function right before LSTM layer `keras.layers.Lambda(lambda tensor : tf.expand_dims(tensor, -1))` to override this error.